# Coincidences between average Catalan tableaux

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, enumerative-combinatorics, young-tableaux, catalan-numbers

There are Catalan number $C_n$ of standard Young tableaux of shape $(n,n)$, which we view as $2\times n$ matrices.  Denote by $P_n$ the average of these matrices:
$$
P_n \, := \, \frac{1}{C_n} \, \sum_{A \, \in \, \text{SYT}(n,n)} A
$$
Note that $P_n=(p_{ij})$ is a rational matrix with entries monotone increasing in rows and columns.  Also, by the 180$^\circ$ rotational symmetry, $p_{ij} + p_{3-i,n+1-j} = 2n+1$. For example, $p_{11}=1$, $p_{2n}=2n$.

The asymptotic density of $P_n$ as $n\to \infty$ is easy to obtain by a direct calculation or via the Brownian excursion (see e.g. [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/PermShapeLong.pdf) or [there](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5156.pdf)), but my question is different.

**Question.** Let $\beta(n):= \min_{(ij)\ne (kl)} |p_{ij}-p_{kl}|$. Is it true that $\beta(n) = o(1)$?

It would be cool if there was an easy way to see this.  I really want a generalization of this result to all large partitions, but at the moment even this is confounding.

UPDATE (May 18, 2019):
Let me explain the motivation behind the question.  Recall the [1/3-2/3 conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/3%E2%80%932/3_conjecture) that every poset $\mathcal P=(X,\prec)$ that is not a linear order contains two elements $x,y\in X$ such that 
$$\frac13 \le P(x\prec y) \le \frac23
$$
For width 2 posets this was shown by Linial in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0213049), but I thought that for shapes $(n,n)$ one can improve $1/3$ to perhaps $(1/2-\varepsilon)$, since we know [so much](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/lectures/Cat/pakcat.htm) about Catalan numbers (including [the average](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/PermShapeLong.pdf) of Catalan objects).  Linial's proof cannot be easily improved, unfortunately.  Now, a beautiful [Kahn-Linial proof](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01275670) of the weaker $1/2e$ bound starts with the average LE of $\mathcal P$.  If $\beta(n)=o(1)$, their argument plus the (earlier) Grünbaum Theorem implies the $(1/e-\varepsilon)$ bound, already a nice result.

Now, Richard's calculaitons give $p_{17} \to 9949/1024 \approx 9.7158$, $p_{23} \to 9.75$. This means that taking $x=(1,7)$ and $y=(2,3)$ in $(n,n)$ gives 
$$0.3553 < \frac1e \left(1-\frac{35}{1024}\right) < P(x\prec y) < \frac2e \left(1+\frac{35}{1024}\right) < 0.6447
$$
for $n$ large enough (unless I miscalculated).  This improvement over $1/3$ bound is good to know, but surely one can do better.

UPDATE (May 27, 2020):
In our most recent paper we found an upper bound $O\bigl(n^{-5/4}\bigr)$ for the sorting probability for these *Catalan posets*.  This problem was stated in the previous update.  Note that we obtained only the upper, but not the lower bounds!

Swee Hong Chan, Igor Pak, Greta Panova,
[Sorting probability of Catalan posets](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/Cat-sort14.pdf), preprint, 2020.

Comment: Another trivial observation that might be useful is that $p_{i,j} \geq p_{i-1,j} + 1$ and $p_{i,j} \geq p_{i,j-1} + 1$.

Comment: Observation 1: for $n \leq 12$: the minimum is obtained at a unique pair $(i,j) \neq (k,l)$ and its 180°-rotation counterpart.

Comment: Observation 2: $|p_{14} - p_{22}| \leq 1$ and $|p_{12}-p_{21}| \leq 2$ for all $4 \leq n \leq 13$, so either of these pairs might be a candidate for a witness for an affirmative answer to your question.

Comment: @ChristianStump: I seriously doubt $(p_{12},p_{21})$ could work.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $p_{21}-p_{12} = C_{n+1} - 2C_{n} - C_{n-1}$. Since $C_{n+1} / C_n \rightarrow 4$, $(p_{12},p_{21})$ is a witness. Or am I too rusty computing limits?

Comment: @ChristianStump: $a_{12}$ will be greater than $a_{21}$ (by only 1) about $1/4$ of the time, because there are $C_{n-1}$ tableaux where the first column is $1,2$. But $a_{21}$ will be greater than $a_{12}$ by at least 1, and in fact sometimes much more, about $3/4$ of the time. So $p_{21}-p_{12}$ is gonna be at least $1/2$, not $o(1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading big O all the time... Please ignore my last two comments, neither of the two pairs are witnesses for small $o(1)$.

Comment: @ChristianStump: A side note - it follows from Richard's formulas below that $p_{21}-p_{12}\to 7/4$ as you originally observed.  This doesn't answer my question, but a good thing to know.

Comment: @IgorPak: I believe the above formula for $p_{21}-p_{12}$ is correct, well, after dividing by $C_n$. Indeed, $C_n \cdot p_{12} = 2C_{n} + C_{n-1}$ and $C_n \cdot p_{21} = C_{n+1}$. This also immediately give $p_{21}-p_{12} \rightarrow 4 - 2 - 1/4 = 7/4$.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a solution, but rather a long comment. Let
$f^{a,b}$ denote the number of standard Young tableaux (SYT)
of shape $(a,b)$. The number of SYT $T$ of shape $(n,n)$
with $T_{1d}=k$ is $f^{d-1,k-d}f^{n-k+d,n-d}$. Hence
  $$ p_{1d} = \frac{1}{C_n}\sum_{k=d}^{2d-1}
    kf^{d-1,k-d}f^{n-k+d,n-d}. $$
There is a similar formula for $p_{2,d}$, though the number
of terms in the sum increases as $n\to\infty$. In
particular,
 \begin{eqnarray*} p_{12} & = & \frac{1}{C_n}\left(
   2f^{n,n-2}+3f^{n-1,n-2}\right)\\ & = &
   \frac{1}{C_n}\left( \frac{2\cdot 3(2n-2)!}{(n+1)!(n-2)!}
   +\frac{3\cdot (2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}\right)\\ & = &
  \frac{3(3n-1)}{2(2n-1)}. \end{eqnarray*}
Write $\bar{p}_{ij}=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}$ (assuming this
limit exists, which I believe is always the case). Thus
$\bar{p}_{12}=\frac 94$.

Similarly,
  $$ p_{21} = \frac{1}{C_n}\left( \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}
     kf^{n-1,n-k+1}\right). $$
Now
  \begin{eqnarray*} \frac{f^{n-1,n-k+1}}{C_n} & = &
    \frac{(2n-k)!(k-1)n!(n+1)!}{n!(n-k+1)!(2n)!}\\
      & \to & \frac{k-1}{2^k}. \end{eqnarray*}
Thus (assuming we can interchange a limit and an infinite sum)
  $$ \bar{p}_{21} = \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{k(k-1)}{2^{k-1}}
      = 4 $$
(modulo computational error). In general, $\bar{p}_{1d}$
  will be given by a finite sum,
  and $\bar{p}_{2d}$ by an infinite series.

**Addendum.** I worked out $\bar{p}_{1d}$ in general, namely,
  \begin{eqnarray*} \bar{p}_{1d} & = & \sum_{k=d}^{2d-1}
    k(2d-k+1)f^{d-1,k-d}2^{-k}\\ & = &
    2^{-2d+1}(d+1)\left(4^d-{2d+1\choose d}\right).
  \end{eqnarray*}
 Beginning with $d=2$, the numbers are
   $$ \frac 94,\ \frac{29}{8},\ \frac{325}{64},\
      \frac{843}{128},\ \frac{4165}{512},\ 
  \frac{9949}{1024},\ \frac{185517}{16384},\dots. $$
We can also write
  $$ \bar{p}_{1,d-1} =2d-\frac{d{2d\choose d}}{4^{d-1}}. $$

**Addendum #2.** I worked out $\bar{p}_{2d}$. If my computation is correct, then
 $$ \bar{p}_{2d} = 2d+\frac{d{2d\choose d}}{4^{d-1}}. $$
Compare with the formula for $\bar{p}_{1,d-1}$ above.

Is there a less computational reason for such simple formulas? Do they extend to shapes other than $n(1,1)$, e.g., $n(1,1,1)$
or $n(2,1)$?

Comment: Richard, nope - I had a completely different thought.  It is quite likely that for some number theoretic reason you don't have a coincidence of the kind you are describing.  Rather, when looking at $(p_{1j} - 2j)$ and scaling everything to $[0,1]$ interval you get density given by the semicircle projection.  Same for $(p_{2j} - 2j)$ but the semicircle is concave, not convex.  Instead of looking at the beginning $j=O(1)$ as you suggest, look at the middle range.  There is no obvious relation between two sets of values, so one would guess that $\beta(n) = O(1/\log n)$.

Comment: One more thing - if you make denominators $4^n$, the numerator sequence is known and computed rather far:  https://oeis.org/A018218  If the other sequence is also known, more values can be checked.

Comment: Echoing what Igor is saying, it seems conceivable that $\beta(n) = o(1)$ without having $\overline{p}_{ij}=\overline{p}_{kl}$ for any $ij, kl$ because there could be e.g. a sequence $(a_n,b_n)$ of indices depending on $n$ with $|p_{1a_{n}} - p_{2b_n}| = o(1)$.

Comment: Asymptotically, Richard's formulas give $2d\pm c\sqrt{d}$ formula which look exactly right from the semicircle POV.

Comment: Imagine a heuristic model where for all $n$ we have $p_{ij}=\overline{p}_{ij}$ exactly (for all $j\leq n$ of course). Then what do Richard's formulas imply that the order of $\beta(n)$ would be?

Comment: @SamHopkins: See more on my motivation in the update to the question.  Richard of course knows all of this.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Indeed, let $n\to \infty$.  Let $a(d) := \overline p_{1d}$, $b(d):=\overline p_{2,d}$.  Then $a(d) = 2d-c\sqrt{d} - c' + O(1/\sqrt{d})$, $b(d) = 2d+c/\sqrt{d} + c' + O(1/\sqrt{d})$, for some explicit $c,c'$.  Then one should be looking at the fractional part of $a(d+\sqrt{d})-b(d) = 2c\sqrt{d} +c'' + O(1/\sqrt{d})$.  It seems, $\sqrt{n}$ mod 1 is ergodic and rates of convergence are relatively well understood https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6387  Thus, if one is careful one can possibly derive $\beta(n) = o(1)$ from here.